# Using data from other JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, layer

```
var non_tfl_lines_Chelsea_HackneyviaKings = L.geoJson(non_tfl_lines_Chelsea_HackneyviaKings, {
    style: function(feature) {
        return {color: feature.properties.color,
                dashArray: '20'}
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return new L.polyline(latlng);
    },
    onEachFeature: popup,
}   
    tfl_stations1, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return new L.Circle(latlng, 400, {
                color: getColor(feature.properties.relief)});
        },
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }
    })   
).addTo(map);
```

How can I use the data from the GeoJSON tfl_stations1 file in the non_tfl_lines_Chelsea_HackneyviaKings layer?

Comment: What language is this? Javascript?

Comment: Your code has a number of syntax problems. The parentheses aren't balanced, there's an extra comma after `popup`, there's a missing comma before `tfl_stations1`. Can you post valid code? And please indent it properly when posting.